# Make `-Wundefined-func-template` a no-op with `-std=c++98`

Tags: c++11, cmake, clang++, c++98

I am trying to maintain a large C++ toolkit: GDCM. The core library is compatible with C++11, but one component (CharLS) is a C++98 only library.

How can I use CMake (monolithic project) so that C++ flags from the toplevel project are not passed down to C++98 only library.

For instance a user may want to exercise the library using clang-3.9 new option: `-Wundefined-func-template`, however this flag should not propagate down to the CharLS compilation line.

I've used an naive fix ([here](https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/commit/d76479747c2d80a9af55cfbdbd4a9a18925d14b5)), but I ([actually upstream too](https://github.com/team-charls/charls/pull/23)) would rather keep CharLS a C++98 (only!) library and not stuff in a [C++11 construct](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-templates#extern-templates).

How one would do that since `-Wundefined-func-template` is not deactivated when used in combination with `-std=c++98`.

Comment: You may add CFLAGS on per-target basis (with `target_compile_definitions` or `target_compile_options`) for top-level project, so these flags wouldn't be passed down. As for using different compilers for different targets, it is not reccomended for CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev where did you read I was using different compilers ?

Comment: I'd propose to make an external project and build this seperatley. For the subproject, you could drop all CXXFLAGS and just add -std=c++98. Or you could filter the properties from `target_get_property` and set the list with `target_set_properties`. But for that you must know all allowed or all not allowed flags. I doubt this will work out in a proper way.

Comment: `where did you read I was using different compilers?` - If this `For instance a user may want to exercise the library using clang-3.9` doesn't mean different compiler, then nevermind. Other part of the my comment is still held.